# Extract files from signed APK - Android Studio Key

Tags: java, android, apk

I was making an app, it took me a while to almost finish it but my pc broken and I only have the .apk on my Nexus 6P.

I've tried to extract (from phone) and decompile but no luck, I think it's because the .apk was signed with the key (Android Studio)..

Can someone help me? Basically the .apk it's not decompiling properly because it's "empty" since was signed.

[image]

EDIT: I tried with dex2jar, SmartJavaDecompiler etc, the result is always the same of the above image.

EDIT2: AppInfo();

```
package com.android.tools.fd.runtime;

public class AppInfo
{
  public static String applicationClass = null;
  public static String applicationId = "com.domain.bonner";
  public static long token = 3064261470052890181L;
  public static boolean usingApkSplits = false;
}
```

Comment: What do you get on the right panel if you click on "(C) AppInfo" in jd_gui?

Comment: @RC. I've edited the post, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

jadx - Dex to Java decompiler
Command line and GUI tools for produce Java source code from Android Dex and Apk files.

https://github.com/skylot/jadx

Comment: This is only a link - it should a comment instead.

Comment: @CharlesMcKelvey Answer of this question will always be a download link. We can't post the whole tool here.

Comment: No, but you could explain what issue the OP is facing, why his solutions didn't work, and why the tool you linked to will work. If all the question is doing is asking for a link to an off site resource it will be closed as such since that is one of the flagging options.

Comment: Don't work, same result like other decompilers .The problem must be 99% on the signed .apk